# Program crashes when abusive word contains space?

Tags: c++, filter

So I'm doing a filter for abusive words for this game that I'm doing some programming on, and if the abusive word contains a space, my program instantly crashes. If the word doesn't contain a space, the word is properly replaced with *beep*. I was wondering if anyone knows why this is occuring. Example of how I'm replacing the word:

```
if (ContainsAbusiveWord(strMsg.c_str()))
{
    if (stricmp(strMsg.c_str(), GetChatFilter()->GetLastFilteredStr().c_str()))
    {
        if (m_nLastAbuseTime < 1) //if user isn't chat blocked
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < GetChatFilter()->GetLastFilteredStr().length(); ++i)
            {
                if (isspace(i))
                {
                    GetChatFilter()->GetLastFilteredStr().erase((remove_if(GetChatFilter()->GetLastFilteredStr().begin(), GetChatFilter()->GetLastFilteredStr().end(), isspace), GetChatFIlter()->GetLastFilteredStr().end()));
                    strMsg.replace(strMsg.find(GetChatFilter()->GetLastFilteredStr()), GetChatFilter()->GetLastFilteredStr().size()-1, "*beep*", GetChatFilter()->GetLastFilteredStr().length() - 1);

                }
            }
            strMsg.replace(strMsg.find(GetChatFilter()->GetLastFilteredStr()), GetChatFilter()->GetLastFilteredStr().size(), "*beep*", GetChatFilter()->GetLastFilteredStr().length());

        }
        else
        {
            return false; //don't send the message
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you are comparing C strings while working with C++ string. No need for that, string already has compare operators.
Second, the *remove_if* returns past-the-end iterator for the new range of the string *GetChatFilter()->GetLastFilteredStr()*. Then, you apply erase for that newly created past-the-end-iterator and *GetChatFilter()->GetLastFilteredStr().end()* which is the old past-the-end iterator. That does not look good to me.
So, why not use *remove_if()* on the string *GetChatFilter()->GetLastFilteredStr()* to remove the space?